# When using a new JTA Transaction, what happens to PersistenceContexts in other transactions?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb, jta

I'm using CMT with a stateless EJB. Suppose I have two methods, one of which is a timeout for an EJB timer and one which modifies existing entities:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
@Timeout
public void cullOldEntities() {

    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();

    CriteriaDelete<T> cd = cb.createCriteriaDelete(clazz);
    Root<T> root = cd.from(clazz);
    Path<Date> dateCreatedPath = root.get("lastUpdated");
    cd.where(cb.lessThan(dateCreatedPath, dateOfExpiry()));
    em.createQuery(cd).executeUpdate();
}

public void modifyEntities(...)
```

As cullOldEntities requires a new transaction, a new persistence context is created and then it is committed when the method ends. The issue is what happens to a preexisting persistence context of another transaction.

1. If  modifyEntities and then cullOldEntities are called so they run concurrently what happens to modifyEntities persistence context if cullOldEntities finishes first and has it's persistence context committed?
2. Does the modifyEntities's persistence context get synchronized with the changes made?
3. If not what will happen when an entity is modified?
4. How can I do a bulk delete that is safe with concurrent modification?

Answer (score 0):

EntityManager not thread safe. So, without Locking last commit will override changes which was made in another transaction.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour (and subsequent effect on design of transaction propagation) depends upon the type of scope being used for persistence context. The two kinds are `Transaction scoped` and `Extended Persistence context` (which can span multiple transactions). For Transaction scoped persistence context  - before the `cullOldEntities()` method call starts,
the container will suspend the transaction inherited if any and will start a new
transaction (because of attribute TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW).  When the entity manager method requiring a transaction is invoked on the entity manager, it will check the current transaction for an active persistence context and none will be found. A new
persistence context will be created starting with that call, and this persistence context will be the
active persistence till the method contextcullOldEntities() ends. Because the transaction
started in cullOldEntities() is different from the earlier one ( if there was one) , the entities managed by the previous persistence context
will not be visible to this new one.

An extended persistence context however is typically scoped to the stateful session bean  to which it is bound.
the extended entity manager of a stateful session bean always uses the same persistence
context. The stateful session bean is associated with a single extended persistence context that is
created when the bean instance is created and closed when the bean instance is removed.

Comment: Can an extended persistence context be used on a stateless EJB?

Comment: It probably would not make sense using it with Stateless as they can service multiple clients in their lilfetime.